# Proj construction in toric geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, toric-geometry, birational-geometry

Let $X$ be a complete toric variety and let $D \subset X$ be a toric divisor which is nef and big. Consider the graded algebra $R(D) = \bigoplus_k H^0(X, kD)$. This is a finitely generated graded algebra and we can consider the projective scheme $Y = Proj(R(D))$.

My question is what is Y?

Do I have some kind of contraction birational maps $X \to Y$?

Note that if $D$ is ample (very ample?) then we indeed have an isomorphism $Y \simeq X$.

Comment: A nef divisor on a toric variety is basepoint-free, so yes, $D$ defines a contraction $X \rightarrow Y$, and since $D$ is also big, this is birational. One description of $Y$ is that it is the result of contracting all the curves $C$ in $X$ such that $D \cdot C=0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you have maybe some reference where I could find those kind of statements?

Comment: The equivalence of nefness and basepoint-freeness on toric varieites is in all the standard references on toric geometry, e.g. Cox--Little--Schenck. (I don't know the precise reference, sorry.) The other parts are covered in the first couple of chapters of Lazarsfeld, Volume 1.